# Object with to-be-defined attributes

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I was wondering if there is a way to define attributes of a class that are not defined until the instance of an object is created. Lets say I want to have a object that works with multiple attributes, in example: *name, width, weight, color*. But some other times I'd like to use the same object to instantiate different properties: *name, length, type, material*.

```
class MultiProduct{
    constructor(atttobedefined1=a1, atttobedefined2=a2, atttobedefined3=a3, atttobedefined4=a4){
        this.atttobedefined1 = a1;
        this.atttobedefined2 = a2;
        this.atttobedefined3 = a3;
        this.atttobedefined4 = a4;
    }
}
var MP = new MultiProduct(name="tesla x",width="280cm",Weight="2000T",Color="Red");
```

At the end, When It comes to show the object on screen, depending on the properties, it would/could be used like:

```
console.log(MP['width']); //in case this property 'width' exists
//output "280cm"
```

Is there any way to get this way or every time I have a different property/real product to be represented I have to create a new object with its setters and getters? I ask this for JavaScript in particular, but I wonder if programmatically (in general) is possible.

Excuse the bad English and the non-sense code written to be used as example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass key/value pairs in an argument, then use an object.

```
new MultiProduct(
    { property: "name", value: "tesla x" },
    { property: "width", value: "280cm" },
    etc
)
```

Or

```
new MultiProduct(
    {
        name: "tesla x",
        width: "280cm",
        etc
    } 
)
```

---

If you want to assign to a property where the name is in a variable, use square bracket notation:

```
const atttobedefined1 = /* How you read from the args depends on the specific forfmat */
this[atttobedefined1] = /* etc */
```

---

Having completely freeform properties will rather lose the benefits of using classes in the first place, so you might want to rethink the approach. You might be better off with just more and optional arguments.

Comment: Thank you. In your approach, how do you declare the class? Could you edit your comment with it, please? Also, you are right, I lose benefits of using classes. However, If I need to develop a web for a, lets say, hardware store, where there are like 3000 types of different products, each with their specifications, what would be the best approach? Is it to create 3000 classes one for each of them?